# Modifying initial values for an AUTO_INCREMENT column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench

I am using MYSQL Workbench, and I have a table called `Customer` and have a primary key `customer_id` which has the INT data type and is auto incremented ("AI" in Workbench column specifications).

This is the DDL code that workbench generates:

```
ALTER TABLE infrastructure.mfg 
CHANGE COLUMN
 mfg_id mfg_id INT(10) UNSIGNED 
NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

My intentions:

- I want to start the numbering at "1000" and auto increment by 100.
- I want the start number to be for only this table

For example:

- 1st = 1000
- 2nd = 1100
- 3rd = 1200
- 4th = 1300

How can I do this? Do I use these functions and if so how?

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
mysql_insert_id()
```

If this is not an option can I check the "G" rather than the "AI"?

If I check "G" the MySQL script that is generated is:

```
ALTER TABLE infrastructure.mfg 

CHANGE COLUMN mfg_id
 mfg_id INT(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL
```

Where is there information on how to use this?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL docs for [`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) explain almost everything about `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns:

> ```
> CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
>     (create_definition,...)
>     [table_options]
>     [partition_options]
>
> -- irrelevant stuff omitted
>
> column_definition:
>     data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
>       [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
>       [COMMENT 'string']
>       [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
>       [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
>       [reference_definition]
>
> -- irrelevant stuff omitted
>
> table_option:
>     AUTO_INCREMENT [=] value
>   | AVG_ROW_LENGTH [=] value
>
> -- many stuff omitted
> ```

There are two `AUTO_INCREMENT` settings, the column attribute and a table option that can change the initial value of the auto incremented column from the default (`1`):

> **Column Data Types and Attributes**
>
> - `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>
>   An integer or floating-point column can have the additional
>     attribute `AUTO_INCREMENT`. When you insert a value of `NULL`
>     (recommended) or 0 into an indexed `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the column
>     is set to the next sequence value. **Typically this is *`value+1`***,
>     where value is the largest value for the column currently in the
>     table. **`AUTO_INCREMENT` sequences begin with 1.**      ...
>
> **Table Options**
>
> - `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>
>   The initial `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for the table. ...

---

So, to add a modify a column with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute that starts from a 100, you do:

```
ALTER TABLE infrastructure.mfg 
    CHANGE COLUMN mfg_id mfg_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 100 ;
```

Test in **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)**

Further information can be found in the related pages of the documentation:

- [Using `AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)
- [`AUTO_INCREMENT` Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-initialization)

Particularly in the last one above, it explains what options you have regarding changing the increment from `1` to `100`. This isn't trivial:

> InnoDB increments the value retrieved by the statement and assigns it to the column and to the auto-increment counter for the table. By default, the value is incremented by 1. **This default can be overridden** by the [`auto_increment_increment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) **configuration setting**.
>
> If the table is empty, InnoDB uses the value 1. This default can be overridden by the `auto_increment_offset` configuration setting.

Test 2 in **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6d5e6a7945c0710ae18054b718aa3a39)**

Note that these two variables **affect all the tables** in the MySQL Server.

Comment: Forgot to add: "Generated columns" feature is irrelevant.